# Publishing messages to a JMS server on another machine

Tags: openmq

I need to publish messages to a topic on a JMS server running on a different machine. The server on the remote machine is Glassfish v3 (OpenMQ). From reading other posts here, I think I need to tell the remote broker to accept JMS messages from a different IP than his own i.e not localhost. Actually, I'd like that remote broker to accept message from remote as well as the local machine.

Problem is, I can't figure out how to configure the remote machine's embedded broker, OpenMQ. I think it is possible from the Glassfish console, but can't figure it out. In jboss you'd execute with a -b 0.0.0.0, but the remote machine is not running jboss. It's Glassfish/OpenMQ. I'm new to all this as you can tell.

I think I know how to set up the JNDI context on the "local" machine that is publishing the messages to the other, remote machine. I've seen examples.

Answer (score 1):

The Glassfish built-in OpenMQ configuration file is:

> GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/imq/instances/imqbroker/props/config.properties

Here you may want to set

> imq.hostname

Though the default seems to be accepting connections from anywhere according to the [docs](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-7755/6n9m8u5md?a=view).