# Publishing messages to a JMS server on another machine

Tags: configuration, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, openmq

I need to publish messages to a topic on a JMS server running on a different machine. The server on the remote machine is Glassfish v3 (OpenMQ). From reading other posts here, I think I need to tell the remote broker to accept JMS messages from a different IP than his own i.e not localhost. Actually, I'd like that remote broker to accept message from remote as well as the local machine.

Problem is, I can't figure out how to configure the remote machine's embedded broker, OpenMQ. I think it is possible from the Glassfish console, but can't figure it out. In jboss you'd execute with a -b 0.0.0.0, but the remote machine is not running jboss. It's Glassfish/OpenMQ. I'm new to all this as you can tell.

I think I know how to set up the JNDI context on the "local" machine that is publishing the messages to the other, remote machine. I've seen examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Publishing messages to a JMS server on another machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907301/publishing-messages-to-a-jms-server-on-another-machine)

Answer (score 0):

When you start the Message Broker (OpenMQ) by your self and not through GlassFish, you can connect to it (have his own jvm)

In Windows, you can start the GlassFish integrated OpenMQ inside the GlassFish Directory (in windows you can start it by:

```
glassfishv3\mq\bin\imqbrokerd
```

In the GlassFish Configuration you can set up the JMS Service **Type** to

```
REMOTE
```

(http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf -> Configuraiton -> Java Message Service)

The other (maybe easier) option is to change the JMS Service Type to LOCAL. So, the GlassFish "manage" the JMS broker, but in an other jvm, which should be reachable by others